# Mysqldump not working in mac

Tags: mysql

I have a question of mysqldump in mac terminal.

```
mysql>mysqldump -u user -ppassword database;
```

But it says:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

I do not know why.

Answer (score 3):

You run `mysqldump` from the shell, not inside the `mysql` command.

Comment: Thanks, I tried in shell. /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppassword database; It says: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

you can remedy this by issuing the following instruction:
ln -s /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock